# Is it a good idea to make an API call with every click?

Tags: performance, go

So I am trying to make an online webpage board game hybrid of chess and Go where the player clicks on the board to place his/her pieces. My problem is, there are a lot of algorithms that come into play in order to make such a board game possible, that are difficult to write out myself. There are good npm packages that already have a lot of that sorted out (I'm thinking primarily of godash), but in order to use the algorithms the packages provide I believe I have to make some sort of data representation of the game,  pass the data to the back-end, use the algorithm on it, and return the result to front-end.

The issue is that, just like chess, the game would require the player to make moves on the board in a relatively short amount of time. The question is, if I decided to make this API call with every move the player makes, would that make my game too slow/unresponsive? Do I have to knuckle down and code those algorithms in front-end so that the game isn't too slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into the [Websocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). You can establish a session between your client and server without having to call your server each time a user plays